# VBA references previous database name

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm sure there is a simple answer to this, but I'm barely literate in VBA.  I have an Access database that I periodically save to a new name after significant changes, but now when I run "Debug" in my added VBA code it still references ("Compile...") the previous database name.  The code runs without error, but anything added after the name change doesn't have any effect.  I have tried renaming the file to the old version without luck, and searched the Access help menus and posts here in SO but haven't been able to find this issue in previous questions with language that I can understand...

Answer (score 0):

You probably only changed the file name. You also need to change the application title, under File -> Options -> Current Database -> Application Title.

Comment: That was something I didn't know, but unfortunately it did not change the compilation target.